# Get current frequency in python with psutil (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, frequency, processor, psutil

I tried to get current frequency of processor with psutil function psutil.cpu_freq(percpu=False).
But as is written in docs "On Linux current frequency reports the real-time value, on all other platforms it represents the nominal “fixed” value".
Is there a way to get current frequency in Windows?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "python windows get actual frequency" yields a Stack Overflow question : [Unable to get current CPU frequency in Powershell or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802420/unable-to-get-current-cpu-frequency-in-powershell-or-python). It says :

> To find the Current Processor Frequency, you have to use the `% Processor Performance` performance counter

So searching for "python windows get performance counter" yields this PyPI library : [winstats](https://pypi.org/project/winstats/). It lets you do :

```py
usage = winstats.get_perf_data(r'\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time',
                               fmts='double', delay=100)
print('    CPU Usage: %.02f %%' % usage)
```

The first parameters to `get_perf_data` is named `counters` and as the doc says must be `Localized Windows PerfMon counter name, or list of.`. Because it **MUST** be localized names, and I don't have an english Windows at hand, I can't reproduce it, but it would work.

If you want your code to work on any language, there are plenty of Stack Overflow questions about that, here is one looking promising : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16364388/11384184

Answer (score 0):

@Lenormju is right, though I found that the `fmt` arg requires an `s`. Could be a recent change to the docs, I'm not sure.

This works for me

```py
usage = winstats.get_perf_data(r'\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time',
                               fmts='double', delay=100)
print('    CPU Usage: %.02f %%' % usage)
```

Comment: indeed, I just checked and you are right. I updated my answer too.